# Operation Automation Tool Recommendation

Tags: java, framework, workflow

Complex huge monolithic code which hundreds of applications use and each one has different cluster which also use a lot of side-services like Solr, Redis, Cassandra ... etc and all of them are on-prem datacetner of tons of physical servers. (I'm not discussing migrating the system to microservices which is in progress but needs years or at least a decade), and all the cluster information for each application like assigned hosts, ports, branches, used side-services are exist per env. in an xml file.

There are a lot of operations, not just deployments, on that datacenter which are dependent and very complicated.

A GUI tool was built for scheduling, tracking and running these complex operations which offers GUI to track and schedule these operations, blocking system, ssh workers control, building workflow using XML for the dependency, parallel deployments capabilities, operations units reusability among the different kind of operations which also use macro workflows that contain different set and order of operation units ...etc

That tool is also a legacy one and hard to maintain for some reasons.

What's important now is that Rundeck was best replacement for that tool, however, we have customized needs which Rundeck doesn't support, I'm not blaming them because our customizations are beyond a service tool to meet.

The question is, is there any framework or platform recommendation to build that tool?